# inserting ignored php code within Maizzle components

Tags: php, html-email, posthtml

I am working on a project using the [Maizzle html-email framework](https://maizzle.com/) that needs to have some php code embedded (but ignored) within the final production build file so that it can get later executed at runtime. Essentially I just want Maizzle to ignore the blocks of php code during the build process.

simplified code to ignore from component file that is included in main template file with the `<component src="compname.html"></component>` tag.

```
...
<p>News for the Week of <rawcode class="rawcode"><?php echo $start_date ?> to <?php echo $end_date ?> from the following categories: <?php echo $cat01, $cat02, $cat03, $cat04 ?></rawcode></p>
...
```

code from config.production.js file

```
 posthtml: {
    plugins: [require('posthtml-custom-elements')()],
    options: {
      directives: [{ name: '?php', start: '<', end: '>' }],
    },
    expressions: {
      ignoredTag: 'rawcode'
    },
  },
```

As long as the php code is directly within the main template file, I have been able to get this to work using the Raw tag to skip over expression parsing, as well as adding the posthtml-custom-elements directive to my config file using the example shown in the Maizzle documentation to skip ignore the php code.

**The Problem:** However, I cannot get this to work if the php code is within a component file that I have included within my template file. Any php code within a component file gets completely stripped out after running "maizzle production build".

I am hoping someone can help with a solution, or if this is just a limitation of how Maizzle works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

This has been fixed in Maizzle [v3.1.6](https://github.com/maizzle/framework/releases/tag/v3.1.6).

---

Mark, I think this might be an issue with the [posthtml-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-modules) plugin that we're using for the Components functionality in Maizzle.

Specifically, its [processWithPostHtml](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-modules/blob/425bd890fe5a0265a584547f93bd15d0f5aa5f78/index.js#L109-L113) method doesn't pass any options to PostHTML rendering, so your `posthtml` config in Maizzle's `config.js` isn't inherited/passed down. That would explain why it works outside components.

I'll need to confirm this with the PostHTML team; hopefully it's an easy fix in `posthtml-modules` and we can pass the user's PostHTML options from the Maizzle config to it, automatically.

I've [created an issue in Maizzle](https://github.com/maizzle/framework/issues/417) for it and will update my response in both places once we find a solution

P.S.: you don't need the `<raw>` tag or the `posthtml-custom-elements` plugin in order to render PHP code, you can safely remove those if not using them for other purposes.

Comment: Many thanks for this update. We've all been waiting for this for a long time 